# How does this fit in with the definition of finite boolean functions?

Tags: functions, logic, definition, computer-science, boolean

My lecture defined that a boolean function is a function f: ${\{0,1\}}^{V} → \{0,1\}$ with $V$ being the set of variables.
Moreover a boolean function f: ${\{0,1\}}^{V} → \{0,1\}$ is finite if  set of "relevant" variables is finite. A variable  is relevant in f if there are two interpretations $I_1,I_2: V → \{0,1\}$ such that $I_1(x) ≠ I_2(x)$ and $f(I_1) ≠ f(I_2)$.

This definition is new to me, as previous lectures defined finite boolean functions as functions:
f: ${\{0,1\}}^{n} → \{0,1\}$.
Can someone please explain (proof?) how my the second definition derives from the first definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that is a finite boolean function under the second definition is also a finite boolean under the first definition.  But the first definition is more general.  It includes some functions that are not finite boolean functions under the first definition.

When $V$ is finite then we know $|V|=n$ for some number $n$.  Since the $n$ in $\{0,1\}^n$ just means “some set of size $n$”, the formulas $\{0, 1\}^n$ and $\{0, 1\}^V$ mean exactly the same thing when $V$ is finite.

The difference arises when  $V$ is an infinite set.  The $\{0,1\}^n$ formula doesn't consider this case.  Let's say that $V$ is the infinite set $$V =\{v_1, v_2,v_3\ldots, v_{10934}, \ldots \}.$$

Now let's consider the function $f : V\to \{0, 1\}$ which is:

$$
f(v_1, v_2, v_3, \ldots) =
\begin{cases}
1,\text{ if both $v_1$ and $v_2$ are $1$} \\
0,\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

$f$ here is a function of an infinite number of variables, but according to the definition, only $v_1$ and $v_2$ matter to the output of the function.  $f$ is really behaving just like the very simple function $$f = v_1\land v_2,$$ except it has an infinite family of inputs that never affect its value.  You can imagine $f$ as a circuit with an infinite number of input wires.  The first two wires are connected to an and-gate, and all the other wires  are  connected to nothing.

[image: boolean circuit as described above]

We may as well ignore the inputs that are not connected (they are “irrelevant”) and just say that $f$ is also a finite boolean function that has two relevant inputs.

Some functions on an infinite set of variables are *not* finite boolean functions under this definition.  For example:

$$
f(v_1, v_2, v_3, \ldots) =
\begin{cases}
1,\text{ if exactly three of the $v_i$ are $1$} \\
0,\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

This function has an infinite number of inputs, and they are *all* relevant, so it's not a finite boolean function under either definition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain how $\{0,1\}^{n}$ and $\{0,1\}^{V}$ mean exactly the same thing when V is finite? $\{0,1\}^{n}$ is a set of n-tuples and $\{0,1\}^{V}$ is a set of functions g: V->{0,1}. I don't see why they are the same.

Comment: What do you think the $n$ means in $\{0, 1\}^n$?

Comment: An $n$-tuple of elements of $S$ can be understood as a function from $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ to $S$.  You tell it the number of the position you are asking about in the tuple, and the function tells you what element of $S$ is at that position.  $S^n$ is just an abbreviation for $S^{\{1, 2,\ldots, n\}}$.

Comment: Now, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, I'm glad I could help.